# Failure to install Python win32 libraries?

Tags: python-2.7

Any ideas? I don't have Python in the path & the company won't allow it. I wouldn't expect it to make a difference to a well written installer, but mention it just in case.

```
H:\code\testgen\pywin32-220>c:\Python27\python.exe  --version
Python 2.7.11

H:\code\testgen\pywin32-220>c:\Python27\python.exe setup.py -q install
Building pywin32 2.7.220.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 1944, in <module>
    """ % dirs).split(),
  File "setup.py", line 594, in __init__
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(sdk_dir, "include", "activdbg.h")):
  File "c:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 65, in join
    result_drive, result_path = splitdrive(path)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 115, in splitdrive
    if len(p) > 1:
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite this post was asked 3 months ago, I faced the same issue today. I found a solution in the end so I would like to share it here. Hope it is still useful.

I found in another post here:
https://www.quora.com/I-tried-to-install-PyWin32-for-Python-2-7-at-Python-for-Windows-Extensions-but-it-did-not-work-How-can-I-install-PyWin32
to **install from the wheel distribution instead.**

In case you have the same connection problem with pip like me, please download the source of wheel via its git repo:
https://bitbucket.org/pypa/wheel/downloads (choose the version you like, latest probably best). Then install it using

> pip install <<_path_to_the_zip_file_downloaded_>>